# Load a Set of StackNavigators on a TabNavigator Stack in React Native >5.xx

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I want two BottomTabNavigators on my screen. Each BottomTabNavigator will have its own StackNavigators like below. Can anyone help me out how this can be achieved on the latest version of React Native?

> Error
> [image]

> **Edited V3** - Still the same error.

> App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {RootNavigator} from './routes';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const Nav = RootNavigator();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Nav />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default App;
```

> routes.js
> I needed separate stacks for Auth and App.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

// Screens:
import SignIn from './components/auth';

import News from './components/news';
import NewsArticleComponent from './components/news/newsArticle';

import Games from './components/games';
import GamesArticleComponent from './components/games/gamesArticle';

// AuthStack - SignIn
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
function AuthScreens() {
  return (
<AuthStack.Navigator>
    <AuthStack.Screen
      name="Auth"
      component={SignIn}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
</AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
}

// News Stack
const NewsStack = createStackNavigator();
function NewsScreens() {
  return (
    <NewsStack.Navigator>
      <NewsStack.Screen name="News" component={News} />
      <NewsStack.Screen name="Article" component={NewsArticleComponent} />
    </NewsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

// Games Stack
const GamesStack = createStackNavigator();
function GamesScreens() {
  return (
    <GamesStack.Navigator>
      <GamesStack.Screen name="Games" component={Games} />
      <GamesStack.Screen name="Article" component={GamesArticleComponent} />
    </GamesStack.Navigator>
  );
}


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppScreens = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreens} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Games" component={GamesScreens} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export const RootNavigator = () => {
  // return createAppContainer({App: AppScreens, Auth: AuthScreens});
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthScreens />
      <AppScreens /> 
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

};
```

> **Edited v5**

*I wanted to navigate from AuthStack.Navigator->Auth to Tab.Navigator->News, the below goNext doesn't work. *

```
goNext = () => {
    // this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
    // this.props.navigation.navigate('AppScreens', {screen: 'News'});
  };
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Screens:
import SignIn from '../components/auth';

import News from '../components/news';
import NewsArticleComponent from '../components/news/newsArticle';

import Games from '../components/games';
import GamesArticleComponent from '../components/games/gamesArticle';

// AuthStack - SignIn/Register - Public
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
function AuthScreens() {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Auth"
        component={SignIn}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export const RootNavigatorAuth = ({updateState}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthScreens />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

// News Stack - Private
const NewsStack = createStackNavigator();
function NewsScreens() {
  return (
    <NewsStack.Navigator>
      <NewsStack.Screen name="News" component={News} />
      <NewsStack.Screen name="Article" component={NewsArticleComponent} />
    </NewsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

// Games Stack - Private
const GamesStack = createStackNavigator();
function GamesScreens() {
  return (
    <GamesStack.Navigator>
      <GamesStack.Screen name="Games" component={Games} />
      <GamesStack.Screen
        name="GamesArticle"
        component={GamesArticleComponent}
      />
    </GamesStack.Navigator>
  );
}

// AppStack - Private
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppScreens = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreens} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Games" component={GamesScreens} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export const RootNavigatorPrivate = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppScreens />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Thanks,

> Zayidu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create the stacks the new way and use it like below.

```
//Imports

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const NewsStack = createStackNavigator();

function NewsScreens() {
  return (
    <NewsStack.Navigator>
      <NewsStack.Screen name="News" component={News} />
      <NewsStack.Screen name="NewsArticleComponent" component={NewsArticleComponent} />
    </NewsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const GamesStack = createStackNavigator();

function GamesScreens() {
  return (
    <GamesStack.Navigator>
      <GamesStack.Screen name="Games" component={Games} />
      <GamesStack.Screen name="GamesArticleComponent" component={GamesArticleComponent} />
    </GamesStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreens} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Games" component={GamesScreens} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer><Tabs/></NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can refer the docs here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Updates

```
App.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootNavigator } from './screens';

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default App;
```

screens.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

// Screens:
import SignIn from './components/auth';

import News from './components/news';
import NewsArticleComponent from './components/news/newsArticle';

import Games from './components/games';
import GamesArticleComponent from './components/games/gamesArticle';


// AuthStack - SignIn
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
function AuthScreens() {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Auth"
        component={SignIn}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
}

// News Stack
const NewsStack = createStackNavigator();
function NewsScreens() {
  return (
    <NewsStack.Navigator>
      <NewsStack.Screen name="News" component={News} />
      <NewsStack.Screen name="Article" component={NewsArticleComponent} />
    </NewsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

// Games Stack
const GamesStack = createStackNavigator();
function GamesScreens() {
  return (
    <GamesStack.Navigator>
      <GamesStack.Screen name="Games" component={Games} />
      <GamesStack.Screen name="Article" component={GamesArticleComponent} />
    </GamesStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppScreens = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreens} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Games" component={GamesScreens} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export const RootNavigator = () => {
  // return createAppContainer({App: AppScreens, Auth: AuthScreens});
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthScreens />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan, 
Thanks for your quick reply. I refactored as you have mentioned, still, I am getting the errors as mentioned below **Edited** section on my main post. Can you help me out! Thanks.

Comment: You will have to create the AuthStack like the same this is a good doc to start with https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/, this will explain you the changes and concepts

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan, Thanks for your reply.
I refactored the AuthStack as well, still get the same error. Can you please check my main post **Edited v2** and give your suggestions on the comment. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan, Thanks for your reply.
I refactored the AuthStack as well, still get the same error. Can you please check my main post **Edited v2** and give your suggestions on the comment. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @ZayiduA you dont have the swithcnavigator now and the navigationcontainer will have to used as a tag for switch navigator you will have to use the below pattern https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan, Thanks for your reply and sorry to bother you again. I am new to React-Native. I refactored as you have mentioned, but still, I am unable to fix it. Can you please check my main post **Edited V3** and give your suggestions on the comment or would you be kind enough to give a code snippet like you did on your first comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you check the answer now, i have updated it with a navigation container, you will have to do it in similar way

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan, 

Still the same error, even after refactoring to your logic. PFB.

export const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthScreens />
      <AppScreens />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Comment: try <NavigationContainer> <AppScreens /> </NavigationContainer> ? you cant have two stacks at the same time

Comment: Yes, I need two stacks like this:
export const RootNavigator = () => {
  // return createAppContainer({App: AppScreens, Auth: AuthScreens});
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthScreens />
      <AppScreens />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Comment: You should go through https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ and change the screens as the switch navigator is not available anymore

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan, I will manage refactoring to different routes for SignIN and SignUp Routes but the logic you have given is still isn't working. I just want to load the AuthScreens as mentioned but it isn't working: 
export const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthScreens />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Comment: i think the problem is RootNavigator() you can directly do <RootNavigator /> instead of the nav can you try that ?

Comment: @ZayiduA check the updated answer, you had mixed up imports from v4 and v5

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan,

You were absolutely right. The last two comments solved the problem, now I need to find a way to do the Private screen stacks. Thanks my man! you are awesome.

Comment: Hello @guruparan-giritharan,

You were absolutely right. The last two comments solved the problem, now I need to find a way to do the Private screen stacks. Thanks my man! you are awesome.

Comment: Edited v5

*I wanted to navigate from AuthStack.Navigator->Auth to Tab.Navigator->News, the goNext doesn't work. * Can you check **Edited v5** on my main post and give your suggestions.